# excel VBA to upload SQL record set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-insert, import-from-excel

I can not figure out how to upload to SQL using Microsoft SQL Server 2012, though I have figured out how to upload record sets to Access using:

```sql
acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
    acImport,
```

SQL data base table is called index, excel worksheet is named index2, data to upload is located in A2:Y2

So far this is what I've come up with..

```sql
Sub upload()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strConnectionString As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim strInsert As String
Dim lngRow As Long

 Set sh = Sheets("index")
 Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

 strConnectionString = "Provider=TRUNCATED" '

 'Start
 cnn.Open strConnectionString

 strInsert = "INSERT INTO index (Qnumber, Margin) VALUES (" & -rs2.Field(Sheets("index2").Range("a1")).Value & ", " & rs2.Field(Sheets("index2").Range("a2")).Value & ");"
 Debug.Print strInsert
 CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailonerror
```

Comment: Which SQL RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Microsoft SQL server 2012

Comment: So, you're trying to load excel data into a SQL server table?

Comment: Yes,i have a excel sheet we calculate prices on , then we take a snippet of that data off the excel sheet and save as a new record in the SQL data base, we have been using this for months now but the old excel was pushing data to a access data base, now we have moved to a sql system and no longer have access.